# Gatsby public folder structure doesn't play nicely with S3 static website hosting

Tags: amazon-s3, gatsby

So, let's say I have a simple Gatsby website with no backend, just plain text with two pages, `index` and `about-us`

Now when I run `gatsby build`, the public folder structure is something like this:

```
├── index.html
├── about-us
│   ├── index.html
```

Problem is, this kind of structure does not play nicely with S3, if I make a request to `mywebsite.com/about-us`, it will actually return a 404. S3 with static hosting enabled does not automatically route to `mywebsite.com/about-us/index.html`, although if I manually browse to that page it would work, but having my routes like that is a nightmare.

Question is, is there some configuration in Gatsby to make it not generate subfolders like this? And instead just create a `about-us.html` in the root folder?

So, I want to achieve the following :

```
├── index.html
├── about-us.html
```

My src/pages structure is the following :

```
├── index.tsx
├── about-us.tsx
```

Comment: Can you provide your /pages folder structure?

Comment: @FerranBuireu pretty standard, but updated the question to include it

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/deploying-to-s3-cloudfront/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [gatsby plugin](http://gatsby-plugin-create-page-html) that kinda does what you are asking but make sure you are setting your canonical urls to prevent [duplicate content](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/duplicate-content) being recorded by search engines.

This is common with gatsby and next js (with trailing slash enabled and a static export). They statically build sites as you are describing with `/path/index.html` and route to the path via `/path/` (notice the trailing slash).

The simplest complete and non-plugin solution is to put your S3 site behind a [CloudFront distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-cloudfront-walkthrough.html) and add a lambda function to redirect all traffic to the right route. I've ran this in production on some small sites my bill is less than 1 USD monthly.

Here is the [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/deploying-to-s3-cloudfront/) docs for this but they use CLI, there are also other references at the bottom of that page.

Here is the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) on how to create a static site with CloudFront distribution.

After you have CloudFront in place, you will need to create a lambda function to behind the scenes redirect `/route/` to `/route/index.html` but show `/route/` in the URL and set the appropriate permissions.

1. Go to lambda and create a new function from scratch using node 14.x.x
2. Click on icon next to index.js
3. Cut and paste the code below and save

Lambda function - The function redirects non trailing slash (`/route`) to trailing slash (`/route/`) which is the same as `/route/index.html`. Also, redirects `/route/index.html` to `/route` for user friendly urls. Lastly, responds with a 301 to tell search engines that only the `/route/` is valid.

```
"use strict";

exports.handler = (event, _, callback) => {
  // Extract the request from the CloudFront event that is sent to Lambda@Edge
  let request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  // Extract the URI from the request
  let oldUri = request.uri;
  // If URI is a file
  const isFile = /\/[^/]+\.[^/]+$/.test(oldUri);
  // If not a file request and does not end with / redirect to /
  if (!isFile && !oldUri.endsWith("/")) {
    return callback(null, {
      body: "",
      status: "301",
      statusDescription: "Moved Permanently",
      querystring: request.querystring,
      headers: {
        location: [
          {
            key: "Location",
            value: `${oldUri}/`,
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
  // Match any '/' that occurs at the end of a URI. Replace it with a default index
  request.uri = oldUri.replace(/\/$/, "/index.html");
  // Return to CloudFront
  return callback(null, request);
};
```

Note - the lambda function was taken from somewhere and I modified it awhile back for this case and I don't remember where it came from - I just cut an pasted if from my lambda.

After you do the above, you will need to edit your CloudFront distribution to accept the lambda function.

1. Go to CloudFront and select your distribution
2. Select the the Behaviors tab, select the default behavior, and click the edit button
3. Lambda Function Associations set - CloudFront Event to Origin Request - then set the Lambda function ARN to the function you just created.

Lastly, you need to [set the IAM permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-permissions.html) so your distribution can access your lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

You can [configure an index document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/IndexDocumentSupport.html#IndexDocumentsandFolders). Then if you visit `mywebsite.com/about-us`, S3 will first look for an object `about-us`. If the `about-us` object is not found, it searches for an index document, `about-us/index.html`.